# Dual stack vs Tunneling IPV6 implementation, which is easy to implement?

Tags: networking, ip, network-protocols

After 1 or 2 years IP address space will be exhausted, so almost all applications need to support IPV6.

I am working on **Client Server Product** and which needs to support IPV6 protocol . Today I read IPv6 material from Net and there are two ways to support IPV6 protocol.

```
 **1. Dual stack
   2. Tunneling**
```

Could you please provide useful information to following questions

1. which is the easy ( minimal code changes in project )  approach to implement IPV6 ? ( Dual stack or Tunneling )
2. which is the best( efficiency, performance and other factors  ) approach to implement    ?
3. How routers need to maintain routing tables for 1. Dual stack and 2. Tunneling approaches.
4. Do we need any extra Hardware support for any one of the approach ?
5. As I mentioned earlier, I am working on Client Server product

   ```
          |   IPv4    IPV6 |    IPv4    IPV6 |
          |----------------|-----------------|
   Client |  yes     no    |  yes      no    |
   Server |  no      yes   |  no      yes    |
   Network|  yes     no    |  no       yes   |
   ```

case1: client and network only IPV4 compatible . But Server only compatible on IPV6

case 2: network and Server IPV6 compatible. But server only compatible with IPV4

If client, server and network supports IPV6 , then there is no **compatibility problem**. but **how we handle above two cases ?** .

1. Please suggest me good material (or text book) for IPV6 implementation on Linux OS.

   ```
   Thanks in advance
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The IPv4 address space is essentially exhausted now, but your conclusion doesn't follow from that premiss. ISPs will probably implement IPv6 over their backbones and continue to provide IPv4 to their customers indefinitely. Most applications don't have to know about IPv6, and some platforms e.g. .NET and Java support it seamlessly under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

"Dual stack vs Tunneling" are options for networks to provide IPv6 connectivity to clients.  They aren't really a concern to application developers - from the application's point of view, the host either has a globally routable IPv6 address or it doesn't.

You generally solve the troublesome cases you mention by ensuring your servers have *both* IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, and making sure that the client software can use either, depending on what the client has available.